# In c++, when I am using multi-level pointer a lot, is it a good way to use typedef to simplify it?

Tags: c++, typedef

In c++, when I am using multi-level pointer a lot, is it a good way to use typedef to simplify it?

Comment: Just to answer more reliably: what is a "multi-level" pointer to you ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, It can be a good practice to increase code readability.

Lets state you have:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo(const myotherlib::x509::certificate& cert);

  private:

    myotherlib::x509::certificate m_cert;
}
```

It is a good idea to typedef things a little bit:

```
class Foo
{
  public:

    typedef myotherlib::x509::certificate cert_type;

    Foo(const cert_type& cert);

  private:

    cert_type m_cert;
}
```

This increases the code readability and has the neat side effect that if you ever change the underlying certificate class, you just have to change the `typedef`.

And to answer more completely, the same rule might apply to "multi-level" pointers: if you really are writting `Foo***` all over the place it can indeed be a good idea to make things more readable, and `typedef` is a good tool for that.

If one day you decide to replace your `Foo***` with a class that has the same semantics, the change will be trivial, not only in your code, but in any client code that uses yours as well.

Comment: Downvoter, care to elaborate ? I never downvoted for revenge (as my profile shows) so please, go ahead.

Comment: I guess that the downvoter thinks you did not answer the question: You explain that typedefing types in namespaces can be useful, but the question is about multi-level pointers: I.e. typedef Foo** FooPtrs;

Comment: @Andre: yes, it might be that. However, my answer do talk about multi-level pointers, just not immediately. To me, this use of typedef makes even more sense for long type names, that's why I chose this example first. Perhaps it was indeed a wrong choice. Not sure it deserves a downvote however (its not like my answer is inherently wrong). Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's always an good idea to have it typedef. For example,

```
typedef int* intp;
typedef int** intpp;
```

Now, if your code is really organized, then you can change simply typedef to use your custom or any other smart pointer. e.g.

```
typedef auto_ptr<int> intp;
```

This can be a good way for debugging.

Comment: Just remember to use different typedefs for different pointers. That is, change the second intp to something else.